# Форма с typeahead, показывающим имя, но со значением id

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

```html
<form action="test.php>" method="post">
    <label for="anything">Что-нибудь</label>

    <div id="remote">
        <input type="text" name="anything" class="typeahead" maxlength="64" 
        required autofocus>
    </div><hr>
    <p><input type="submit" name="saveChanges" value="Сохранить изменения"></p>
</form>
```

```js
<script>
var users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Зачем это вообще?'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: {
        url: 'autocomplete.php?text=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

$('.typeahead').typeahead({ minLength: 1 }, { source: users });
</script>
```

autocomplete.php

```
<?php
    $text = $_GET['text'];
    $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $sql = "SELECT id, nickname FROM users WHERE nickname LIKE '$text%'
        ORDER BY nickname DESC LIMIT 5";
    $st = $conn->query($sql);

    $users = array();
    foreach($st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $users[] = $row;
    }

    $conn = null;

    echo json_encode($users);
?>
```

test.php

```php
<?php
    if(is_numeric($_POST['anything'])) echo "Всё работает";
?>
```

Необходимо, чтобы после нажатия кнопки в `$_POST` находился `id`, а не `nickname`, но при этом чтобы в `input[name=anything]` показывался `nickname`.
Буржуи много чего пишут, но там либо старое, либо не рабочее (у меня). Наиболее правдоподобное (хотя тоже не работающее) решение:

```js
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    minLength: 1
},
{
    source: users
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data) {
    $('.typeahead').val(data.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее подходящий для Вас вариант в HTML это:

```
<select name="userid">
   <option value="id1">nickname1</option>
   <option value="id2">nickname2</option>
</select>
```

В результате форма будет передавать userid=idXXX.
Естественно перед выбором ника нужно чтобы все ники и их id были заполнены на странице.

Comment: Это даже не рассматривается: пользователь должен писать данные и автозавершением, выборкой данных из БД, они должны подставляться, иначе мне придется тысячи 'option' делать.

Comment: Но это не мешает Вам сделать такое поле скрытым, и с помощью ajax получать список ников и id и динамически заполнять на основании вводимого текста. Ведь пользователь может написать ник, которого в базе нет, и какой id вы тогда надеетесь получить?

Comment: Я сделал скрытое текстовое поле и в коде выше вместо `$('.typeahead')` просто подставил это поле. Спасибо за подсказку.